# Use the same class with rabbitmq and JPA

Tags: jpa, playframework, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use the same class, a class extends play.db.jpa.Model, in rabbitmq and JPA mixed application. But it always failed with rabbitmq exception : Unrecognized field "persistent" when receiving with a class extends from RabbitMQConsumer. Any suggestion?

Comment: solved, add annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) before the header of that class

Comment: If you found an answer to your own question, it is recommended to add a real answer below and accept that as the right one. Not everyone reads every comment.

Comment: I can't add at that time because my low reputation. Now it's ok.Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, add annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) before the header of that class